# Socket.io broadcast.emit is not working but it works without broadcast

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to send a message to everyone except the sender.

server.js

```
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   socket.on('typing', (msg) => {
     io.broadcast.emit('typing', msg);
   });
  });
```

cleint.html

```
var socket = io();
socket.emit('typing', 'some message');
socket.on('typing', (msg) => {
    $('#myLabel').append(msg);
});
```

If i remove the broadcast in server to just io.emit then it works, but the sender also sees the message.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
io.broadcast.emit('typing', msg);
```

try

```
socket.broadcast.emit('typing', msg);
```